# Go — how to handle common fields between struct types

Tags: types, struct, go

If I have two types:

```
type A struct {
      X int
      Y int
}

type B struct {
      X int
      Y int
      Z int 
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the following without needing two methods, given that both access identically-named fields and return the sum of them?

```
func (a *A) Sum() int {
     return a.X + a.Y
}

func (b *B) Sum() int {
     return b.X + b.Y
}
```

Of course, were X and Y methods, I could define an interface containing these two methods. Is there an analogue for fields?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Embed `A` in `B`.

```
type A struct {
      X int
      Y int
}

func (a *A) Sum() int {
     return a.X + a.Y
}

type B struct {
      *A
      Z int 
}

a := &A{1,2}
b := &B{&A{3,4},5}

fmt.Println(a.Sum(), b.Sum()) // 3 7
```

http://play.golang.org/p/fjT9c-m_Lj

But no, there's no interface for fields. Only methods.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you chose to embed a pointer to A in B, rather than directly embedding A in B. Care to share?

Comment: @jpp: Just because OP had the method on a pointer receiver, so I thought it would be more clear. Also in some cases it makes a difference, like if `B` is also a value instead of a pointer, and is attempted to be passed as an interface, like this: http://play.golang.org/p/k2e5saB7OI But that doesn't seem likely given this example.